# Is there a way to convert string to binary data to reduce size?

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, compression, binaryfiles

I implemented Huffman coding (it is a study task). I get some text string as input, and I produce some result string, like as: "011010 00101 0110 0101 0110 0101 0111 0000 0010 0000 0110 0010 0110 1111 0110 1111 0111 0000 0010 0000 0110 0010 0110 0101 0110".

```
string some_text = read_text_file_to_string(text_file);

string coded_string = encode_string(some_text); // coded_string == "011010 00101 0110 0101..."
```

Is there a way to transform **coded_string** to binary format and write it to file? My aim is reducing size of input data. But, if I write **coded_string** to file, I get more bigger a file.

Comment: Can you use std::bitset?

Comment: Normally, you accumulate bits together until you have a whole byte, then write the byte out to disk. When reading them back in, you read entire bytes at a time, and figure out how many bits go in the current group of bits based on when you reach a leaf in your tree. At the very end, you may have to add some padding to get to a whole byte.

Comment: @Niall, yes, I can. But I don't understand how to reduce size of data with help a bitset.

Comment: I it will take a string as an argument, so you can choose the size and them it has "to_ulong" that return integers that you can write to file. Internally it is often asked as an integral or an array of integrals.

Comment: As far as I know bitset consume alot of extra space - if you looking for "the smaller - the better" implement the functions you need yourself, in example, by shifting

Comment: Are the spaces significant?

Comment: If the characters in the string are more than just 0 and 1 (from another comment of yours), you look at a BCD scheme and pick up on the suggestion from @JerryCoffin.

Comment: @cdhowie, no, they are not. It may be another delimiter.

Comment: @Niall, I made a typo. There are only 0, 1 and space.

Comment: Ok, you can still chunk it 4 characters at a time and map that to a hexadecimal character to write to file.

Comment: @Denis I mean do you need to retain the spaces in the output, somehow? Are they important to the data in any way?

Comment: Since it's Huffman coding, the spaces are not needed. The length (number of bits) of a Huffman code is determined by the leading bits of each code element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that spaces are not significant, I will assume that anything other than a 0 or a 1 can be ignored.  In that case, you can use this function to write it out to a file stream.  Note that the last octet will be right-padded with zeroes, so if the input number of bits isn't exactly divisible by 8, you need to account for this somehow, possibly by writing out the number of bits in the last octet somewhere else (perhaps after the data).

```
void write_bits(std::ostream & output, std::string const & input)
{
    unsigned char c;
    int bits = 0;

    for (auto i = output.begin(); i != output.end(); ++i) {
        if (*i == '0' || *i == '1') {
            c = (c << 2);
            if (*i == '1') {
                ++c;
            }

            if (++bits == 8) {
                output << c;
                c = 0;
                bits = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (bits > 0) {
        while (bits < 8) {
            c <<= 2;
            ++bits;
        }
        output << c;
    }
}
```

For the `output` parameter you can pass an `std::ofstream` in order to write the output to a file, or you can use an `std::ostringstream` to write the data into a memory structure that can be converted into an `std::string`.

Comment: Shouldn't the output line be: output << c; ?

Comment: Note that your Huffman encoding should include a bit pattern for an end of data code, so that any bits after that end of data code due to padding to a byte (or some other) boundary are ignored.

Comment: @rcgldr Indeed it should.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is ALWAYS 4 characters and a space after that, you can convert 8 numbers to byte -> the binary value ot the 8 digits (http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal), you may also need a flag that will tell if the last 4 digits are actualy 4 or 8 representation. but that it I think...

Comment: Unfortunately, the pattern is not always 4. It is my bad example.

Comment: what are the leagle characters for the string?

Comment: 0-1 and space are leagle characters for the string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with text input and even if using files, there's probably enough memory to hold both the entire file and the encoded data in ram. You could choose to directly encode the text string into a binary buffer, then create a function to convert the Huffman codes from the binary buffer into text display strings as shown in the original question.

When allocating space for the binary buffer, assume the worst case scenario. For example if the longest code is 12 bits, then the maximum number of bits would be 12 x (n+1) rounded up to some convenient boundary, where n is the number of bytes in the text file, and the +1 is used for the end of data code.

It would probably be useful to create a program that can encode a text file to a Huffman binary file, and another program that can decode a Huffman file to a text file.